# React Native geolcation number of satterlites

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, geolocation, location

anyone know how to get the number of satellites in react native. currently, I'm using 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation 
But it doesn't give a number of satellites

Answer (score 0):

for  Android, you can get the inf by the native module. in the android native, you can use `localManager` to get the number of satellites.

```
privateLocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

//it uses GPS, so you have to check if GPS is working

//add the listener
manager.registerGnssStatusCallback(gpsStatusListener);

private GpsStatus.Callback gpsStatusListener = new GpsStatus.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSatelliteStatusChanged(GnssStatus status) {
        int count = status.getSatelliteCount()
    }
};
```

for how to write react-native native module you can see the official document;
for ios, it can not get the info.

you can also use this [react-native-location-satellites](https://github.com/anooj1483/react-native-location-satellites/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/synclovis/RNLocationSatellitesModule.java) to get.